# In gtmetrix I have error add expire headers. How to remove this?

Tags: php

I have added this code to `.htaccess` file still gtmetrix is reporting add expiry headers. Do i need to install some modules on cpanel .?

```
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|xhtml|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                ExpiresActive On
                ExpiresDefault A0
                ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
                ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
                ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
                ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
                ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
                ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
                ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
                ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
                ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
                ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
       </IfModule>
     <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
                Header unset ETag
                Header set Connection keep-alive
                FileETag None
    </IfModule>
```

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml

Comment: Have you checked on your own whether these headers took effect? Additionally, why did you tag this question with php?